# How to bring the value from peoplesoft to autocomplete using jquery and ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, autocomplete, peoplesoft

Currently working on jquery where I am using auto complete functionalities with my current code autocomplete working fine with ajax. I am new to peoplesoft Iscript inside that the ajax value i need to get peoplesoft database value. Can kindly please help me

Here is my code for autocomplete

```
    $("#suggest").autocomplete({
    delay: 100,
    source: function (request, response) {

        // Suggest URL
        var suggestURL = "http://suggestqueries.google.com/complete/search?client=chrome&q=%QUERY";
        suggestURL = suggestURL.replace('%QUERY', request.term);

        // JSONP Request
        $.ajax({
            method: 'GET',
            dataType: 'jsonp',
            jsonpCallback: 'jsonCallback',
            url: suggestURL
        })
        .success(function(data){
            response(data[1]);
        });
    }
});
```

Here is the [fiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/karthic2914/Muv6e/2/)

Thanks in advance

Comment: What tools version are you on?

Comment: What are you trying to do?   You want to do another AJAX call to an IScript or is this inside of an IScript already?

Comment: @Jared thanks for the reply instead of the url (Dummy Url) is that possible to bring the data from the peoplesoft database

Comment: See updated answer.  Try that out.

Answer (score 0):

This is how you could achieve it.  There may be more work done to make the JSON match depending, but I believe this will work.

SQL.MY_QUERY:

```
SELECT TEXT FROM MY_TEXT_TABLE WHERE TEXT LIKE ':1%';
UNION
SELECT TEXT FROM MY_TEXT_TABLE WHERE TEXT LIKE '%:1';
```

WEBLIB_THIS.FIELDNAME.FieldFormula.IScript_this:

```
Local String &str_Query;
Local String &str_JSON;
Local String &str_Result_Text;
Local SQL &oSQL;
Local Array &arr_Results;
Local Integer &i;

/* Get the query parameter */
&str_Query = Unencode(%Request.GetParameter("q"));

/* Instantiate your array */
&arr_Results = CreateArray();

/* Build your SQL Query */
&oSQL = CreateSQL(SQL.MY_QUERY, &str_Query);

/* Execute and loop thru the SQL results */
While &oSQL.Fetch(&str_Result_Text)\
    /* Push your results into the array */
    &arr_Results.Push(&str_Result_Text);
End-While;

/* JSON Array */
&str_JSON = "[" | """" | &str_Query | """" | "," | "[";

/* Loop thru the array and build the JSON string */
For &i = 1 to &arr_Results.Len
   &str_JSON = &str_JSON | """" | &arr_Results [&i]  | """";
   If &i < &arr_Results.Len then
       &str_JSON = &str_JSON | ",";
   End-If;
End-For;

/* Close the JSON array */
&str_JSON = &str_JSON | "]";

/* Close the JSON array */    
&str_JSON = &str_JSON | "]";

/* Set the content type */
%Response.SetContentType("application/json;");

/* Send the response */
%Response.Write(&str_JSON);
```

HTML.MY_OBJECT_NAME or JS file, document, etc:

```
    $("#suggest").autocomplete({
    delay: 100,
    source: function (request, response) {

        // Suggest URL
        var suggestURL = "http://host.domain.com/psc/SITENAME/PORTAL/NODE/s/WEBLIB_THIS.FIELDNAME.FieldFormula.IScript_this?q=%QUERY";
        suggestURL = suggestURL.replace('%QUERY', request.term);

        // JSONP Request
        $.ajax({
            method: 'GET',
            dataType: 'jsonp',
            jsonpCallback: 'jsonCallback',
            url: suggestURL
        })
        .success(function(data){
             response(data[1]);
        });
    }
});
```

FWIW: Using a search index would be much quicker, you could do your own research on that.